# Xcode "po" command retains value

Tags: swift, xcode

I've been debugging my code and found that my manager was deinitialised (that was cause of my bug - not calling delegate methods).

What's strange, that during debugging process I've used "po" command after setting the manager's delegate (weak) and it prevented it from being deinitialised (delegate methods were called).

Why is that? Is it proper behaviour?

Xcode 8.3, swift 3.1

EDIT:

```
//a tap starts everything :)

    @IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let requestManager = FacebookPostRouteRequest() //bug fixed by changing to instance variable
        requestManager.delegate = self
        requestManager.showShareBadgeDialog(self.badge!, onViewController: self)
    }

//in FacebookPostRouteRequest
        final weak var delegate: FacebookPostRouteRequestDelegate?

        func showShareBadgeDialog(_ badge: Badge, onViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
            let dialog = self.initDialog(onViewController: viewController)
            guard let imageURL = badge.imageURL else {
                self.delegate?.facebookPostRouteRequest(self, didCompleteWithResult: false)
                return
            }

            dialog.shareContent = self.generateImageShareContent(imageURL)
            self.show(dialog)
        }

 private func show(_ dialog: FBSDKShareDialog) {
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            dialog.delegate = self //when printed out dialog.delegate delegate methods were called! Deinit of FacebookPostRouteRequest is not called.
            let showResult = dialog.show() 
            ...
            }
        }

extension FacebookPostRouteRequest: FBSDKSharingDelegate {
    func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
        ...
    }
        //other delegate methods implemented as well

}
```

Comment: It's impossible, show a code you are debugging

Comment: Updated with code. After calling po deinit of FBPostRouteRequest is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    let requestManager = FacebookPostRouteRequest()
    requestManager.delegate = self
    requestManager.showShareBadgeDialog(self.badge!, onViewController: self)
}
```

After the last line, the `requestManager` object will be disposed because it's no longer referenced and will not call any of the delegate methods.

Make `requestManager` an instance variable:

```
let requestManager = FacebookPostRouteRequest()
@IBAction func shareButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    requestManager.delegate = self
    requestManager.showShareBadgeDialog(self.badge!, onViewController: self)
}
```

Your issues with the debugger are probably race conditions for stopping the main thread.

Comment: That's true, I solved it like that. I was just wondering why does the "po" prevents from deinit.